# Eclipse - Plugin Installation Error

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Eclipse Version I have: 
Version: 3.4.1 (Ganymede)
Build id: M20080911-1700

I am having an error installing any plugin for eclipse. I didn't have that problem but suddenly now I can't get any plugin installed like PMD, JADclipse, etc.

The error I get is:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  No repository found containing: org.aspectj.ajde/osgi.bundle/1.6.4.20090106083800
  No repository found containing: org.aspectj.runtime/osgi.bundle/1.6.4.20090106083800
  No repository found containing: org.aspectj.weaver/osgi.bundle/1.6.4.20090106083800
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.core/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.examples/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.source/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.source/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.ui/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.aspectj/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.visualiser/osgi.bundle/2.2.0.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.mylyn.ui/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
```

I tried taking the following steps but didn't work either -

```
•Software Updates -> Manage sites -> Export (bookmarks.xml)

•exit eclipse

•go to your eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.*.prefs and delete files (after backup)

•Restart eclipse

•re-import bookmarks.xml
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score -1):

This is a [common error with p2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248694) in Eclipse < 3.5. [See my blog for a solution](http://blog.pdark.de/2008/09/29/installing-eclipse-341-despite-p2/).